# What could produce the XML Layout file in notification bar?

Tags: android, xml, notifications

I'm having a really weird problem.

I'm building an Android application which uses beacons to receive some notifications. The problem is that, besides the notifications that I should receive, I also get a notification with the path to a XML file (not every time the same). In the code, there is nothing that could point to it.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

[image]

### Code for Beacons

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = intent
            .getParcelableArrayListExtra(OnyxBeaconApplication.EXTRA_COUPONS);

    if (coupons == null || coupons.size() == 0) {
    } else {
        String couponsListAsString = mSharedPref.getString(
                COUPONS_LIST_ENTRY, SHARED_PREF_NO_ENTRY);
        ArrayList<Coupon> couponsFromStorage = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
        ArrayList<Coupon> newCoupons = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
        if (!couponsListAsString.equals(SHARED_PREF_NO_ENTRY)) {
            couponsFromStorage = (ArrayList<Coupon>) gson.fromJson(
                    couponsListAsString, new TypeToken<List<Coupon>>() {
                    }.getType());
            for (Coupon couponReceived : coupons) {
                boolean couponFound = false;
                for (Coupon couponFromStorage : couponsFromStorage) {
                    if (couponReceived.couponId == couponFromStorage.couponId) {
                        couponFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!couponFound) {
                    newCoupons.add(couponReceived);
                }
            }
        }

        couponsFromStorage.addAll(newCoupons);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(COUPONS_LIST_ENTRY,
                gson.toJson(couponsFromStorage));
        editor.commit();

        mCouponCounter = mSharedPref.getInt(COUPONS_NEW_COUNTER, 0);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_COUPONS, coupons);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        long[] vibratePattern = { 500, 500, 500, 500 };
        for (Iterator<Coupon> ci = coupons.iterator(); ci.hasNext();) {
            ++mCouponCounter;
            Coupon c = ci.next();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context)
                    .setContentTitle(c.name)
                    .setContentText(c.message)
                    .setContentInfo(
                            mCouponCounter > 1 ? "+ "
                                    + (mCouponCounter - 1) + " new more"
                                    : "")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setGroup(COUPON_KEY)
                    .setGroupSummary(true).setVibrate(vibratePattern)
                    .setLights(Color.BLACK, 500, 500)
                    .setSound(notificationSound);

            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(COUPONS_TAG, 1, builder.build());

            editor.putInt(COUPONS_NEW_COUNTER, mCouponCounter);
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (mCouponListener != null) {
            mCouponListener.onCouponsReceived(coupons);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they're actually coming from your app ?

Comment: Yes. If I'm holding my finger on it and try to see its details, it points to my app details.

Comment: They could also be coming from any add-on library/sdk you are using to discover the beacons, as well as any other program you might have installed which also monitors for such.  Incidentally, your link target is not shared with the public.

Comment: Are those xml files available in your code?  And can you post the code you are using to get the notifications?

Comment: Screenshot not working

Comment: Yes, those XMLs are available in my code.

Comment: I'm using the Onyx Beacons library for working with the beacons. I will edit the original post and add the code used to receive the notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Turned out it was a bug in their library. They hadn't published the updated library yet, but they sent me a new one.